# general problem- sets,python

Tags: python, set

I got a problem:

keys here is a list.

```
keys = [(6,4) , (6,8)]
```

The entries in the keys can be 4,5...or watever

Now, I have to pick up only 1 from it.So I used:

```
root = keys[0]
print root
```

output: (6,4)

Now I have to make a set which is empty, say,...

```
closed = set()

for u,v of root:
   if v not in closed:
      closed.add(v)
      for val in closed:
         print val
```

It should add values to the set i.e 6 and 4. How should I implement it? The above method is right or wrong? I tried, but not giving me the right ans

Comment: ... So what are you looking for?

Comment: you'll have to be more specific...

Comment: it is giving me an error....TypeError

Comment: TypeError: unpack non-sequence

Comment: @gnibbler's answer looks correct and should be accepted if you feel it answers your question. If you feel it doesn't please specify why not.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> keys = [(6,4) , (6,8)]
>>> root = keys[0]
>>> closed = set()
>>> closed.update(root)
>>> closed
{4, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to add the 6 and the 4 into your set:

```
closed = set()
closed.add(root[0])
closed.add(root[1])
```

But maybe you should explain a bit more, what you are trying to do. Then we could help you better.

---

The line `for u,v of root:` will not compile. (6,4) is a tuple, which
is an [immutable sequence type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). You can get its values with the []
operator (like in my code above) or you could unpack it like this:

```
(u,v) = root
```

If you want to add both values, you should include this call in your
code:

```
closed.add(u)
```

The code:

```
if v not in closed:
    closed.add(v)
```

is equivalent to:

```
closed.add(v)
```

A set ensures, that each element is contained only once.

Comment: basically, root = (6,4) has 2 values in it. I need to check if both of these values are inside my set or not. But it is giving me a type error: unpack nonsequence

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to do:

```
keys = [(6,4) , (6,8)]
closed = set()
map(closed.update, keys)
```

By the way, this is a bit redundant:

```
if v not in closed:
    closed.add(v)
```

You can just do:

```
closed.add(v)
```

If v is in closed already, nothing happens.